# Liquibase not recognizing the change set

Tags: liquibase

Tried SQL tags as well as 'addColumn' Seems like liquibase doesn't even recognize the changeset

```
        <databaseChangeLog
                xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">
                <changeSet id="CHD_ID" author="UserA" dbms="postgresql">
                        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
                                <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">
                                        SELECT COUNT(CHECKED) FROM (
                                        SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) CHECKED FROM DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE ID='CHG_ID'
                                        ) COUNT_CHECK;
                                </sqlCheck>
                                <tableExists tableName="XXX"/>
                        </preConditions>
                        <comment>Adding columns to store the info</comment>
                        <!--
                        <addColumn tableName="XXX" schemaName="yyy">
                            <column name="XXX_COLA" type="varchar(50)"></column>
                        </addColumn>
                        <addColumn tableName="XXX" schemaName="yyy">
                            <column name="XXX_COLB" type="varchar(50)"></column>
                        </addColumn>
                        -->
                        <sql>
                                ALTER TABLE XXX ADD COLUMN XXX_COLA TYPE VARCHAR(50);
                        </sql>
                        <sql>
                                ALTER TABLE XXX ADD COLUMN XXX_COLB TYPE VARCHAR(50);
                        </sql>
                </changeSet>
        </databaseChangeLog>
```

Not sure what am I missing, Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you be more specific? What command(s) are you running? Can you run those with  `--logLevel=DEBUG` and share the log files? What version of Liquibase are you using? What database platform?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve, Here is the output ./liquibase --logFile a.txt --logLevel=DEBUG --changeLogFile scripts/changesetfile.xml update
Starting Liquibase at Fri, 20 Mar 2020 14:34:20 EDT (version 3.6.3 built at 2019-01-29 11:34:48)
Liquibase: Update has been successful. , I am using postgres

Comment: the script has the following command, java -cp "$CP" $JAVA_OPTS liquibase.integration.commandline.Main ${1+"$@"} java options are standard

Comment: OK, so you are basically running `liquibase update`, and you are expecting that since the database does not have the columns XXX_COLA and XXX_COLB that the changeset will be applied and run. The thing that I find unusual is that you are using a precondition block and using the sqlCheck to check the DATABASECHANGELOG table - you should not need to do that at all. That is built into Liquibase. Having the tableExists precondition seems OK. 
What is the content of the DATABASECHANGELOG table? Also just noticed a typo - the precondition is looking for `CHD_ID` but the ID of the changeset is `CHG`

Comment: Also, know that if you use a precondition and set the `onFail="MARK_RAN"`, then if you only had the 'tableExists' precondition and the table did NOT exist, it would mark the changeset as run, and would not ever try to run it again. It might be better to just leave that attribute off and have the update HALT in that condition.

Comment: Thank you very much @Steve it turned out I was looking at a different schema, the change set was executed correctly

Comment: It was indeed a typo while posting this issue, I was trying to mask the information